# Can I navigate zsh's tab-completion menu with vi-like hjkl keys?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, line-editor

I use zsh's menu-based tab completion. I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> once, and a list of possible completions appears. If I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again, I can navigate this list with the arrow keys. However, is it possible to navigate them with the `vi`-like <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd> keys instead?

I use emacs mode for command-line input, with `bindkey -e` in `~/.zshrc`. I also use [zim](https://github.com/Eriner/zim) with zsh. If relevant, the commands that specify the tab-completion system are [here](https://github.com/Eriner/zim/blob/4ac66646c496225ce8a8714b6a2fcabff32aa851/modules/completion/init.zsh#L18).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, you can by enabling `menu select`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select
zmodload zsh/complist
...
# use the vi navigation keys in menu completion
bindkey -M menuselect 'h' vi-backward-char
bindkey -M menuselect 'k' vi-up-line-or-history
bindkey -M menuselect 'l' vi-forward-char
bindkey -M menuselect 'j' vi-down-line-or-history
```

Comment: +1 This works well if I manually run the `bindkey` commands in the terminal, but it fails if I put them at the end of `~/.zshrc`, with `/home/sparhawk/.zshrc:bindkey:186: no such keymap \`menuselect'`.

Comment: Did you enable the completions scripts? See the command before the ellipses...

Comment: Do you mean the `zstyle` line? Yes, I had that in `~/.zshrc` too.

Comment: You have to [enable it as well](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#Command_completion). See my [.zshrc as an example](https://bitbucket.org/jasonwryan/shiv/src/tip/.zsh/zshrc).

Comment: Adding `autoload -Uz compinit` and `compinit` didn't work, but I'm not sure if enabling it is the problem, because (a) menu select works fine in a general sense, and always has, and (b) I can manually run the `bindkey` lines later, which works. Also, I just realised (b) only works if I press tab *first*, presumably to initialise the completion system, then run `bindkey…`. Otherwise it fails as above (`bindkey: no such keymap \`menuselect'`).

Comment: See [the Zsh docs for the details](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide06.html).

Comment: I worked it out from paring down your `~/.zshrc`. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 5):

The closest I've come to this is using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> to move forward and backward through the list of possible completions, instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>. This *is* more `vi`-like navigation.

In a config `.zsh` file I achieve this with:

```
bindkey '^n' expand-or-complete
bindkey '^p' reverse-menu-complete
```

And relatedly:

```
bindkey '^k' up-history
bindkey '^j' down-history
bindkey '^h' backward-delete-char
bindkey '^w' backward-kill-word
bindkey '^r' history-incremental-search-backward
```

Here are the docs for the [bindings](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Standard-Widgets).

Comment: it is great, thanks. also, `-M menuselect` can be added to `bindkey` command to restrict the mode here.

Comment: I love it, Do you have more useful configs?